# load menu and submenus ,partialview jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, razor, partial-views

I have a controller which returns partialview and data.

```
return PartialView(@"~/Views/Shared/Menu/Menu.cshtml", result.Result);
```

Then i call this controller in javascript to load menus on my razor page like this

```
$('#primary-menu').load(url);
```

The problem is when page loaded i can display menus on my page, but all parent menus expanded on page load. I need to load menus dynamically but when i try to load data as partial view, parent menus expand on load and i cant prevent that. But if i add the html statically it works fine , menus don't expand on load. How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is inside the partial view. But I am making an assumption that there is some initialisation script which is not getting invoked during **$.load** call. If that is the case can you just check by adding simple **console.log** statements.
Otherwise can you try execute the script on success.

```js
$.('#primary-menu').load(url, function() {
   // initialise your menu here (assuming its some kind of component)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, controller returns partialview and model, i fill the html with this model recursively(parent-child relationship) , i can load menu in load callback as you mentioned, but i need to use partialview so i dont know how to fill partialview in jquery

Comment: So there is no script. Are you using any css to expand and collapse the menu. Is it possible that style sheet file is referenced in that same partial view and its not getting downloaded when you use $.load. But when you paste the html browser downloads it. In that case you can move the stylesheet to head or bundle it before hand.

Comment: Its not possible,I am not using css for expanding or collapsing, just template css. I did the same thing in another project with another template and it works fine, but this time i can't even close the expanded menu because theres no collapse icon, it only works with static html its interesting.

Comment: then might be something wrong/bug in the way view is implemented. You can simply return the html which is working from the partial view and confirm that there is no script & css issue.